# Sorbet asking a `sig` for `attr_reader`

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Sorbet is showing an error for the attr_reader, but correct me if I am wrong, sigs are required when the function is declared, not called, right?

I have tried going through the documentation but all I got is this note

Note: Many Ruby constructs that look like local variables are actually method calls without parens! Specifically, watch out for attr_reader and zero-argument method definitions.

```
app/util/hodor.rb:125: This function does not have a `sig` https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference#7017
     125 |  attr_reader(:collection_name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Where does this line of code appear? They normally are contained in class or module definitions.

Comment: Hm, sorbet playground doesn't give this error

Comment: This error is silenced in all strictness levels below `# typed: strict`. The playground defaults to `# typed: true` if no sigil is given. In all other places Sorbet defaults to `# typed: false` if no sigil is given.

https://sorbet.org/docs/static

Answer (score 7):

The error does not have to do with the `attr_reader` method itself needing a `sig`, but with `:collection_name`. The signature for `attr_reader` is already known, but the new method it dynamically creates, `#collection_name` does not have a known `sig`, and Sorbet expects this to be the place where you give it one.

You can do this to fix it:

```rb
sig { returns(String) }
attr_reader(:collection_name)
```

Comment: Is it correct that an `attr_reader` that defines multiple attributes will have to be split up over multiple lines to make the signatures work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`attr_reader(attribute)` is the equivalent of :

```rb
def attribute
  @attribute
end
```

This is probably why Sorbet is asking for a sig.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Sorbet [documentation](https://sorbet.org/docs/faq#how-should-i-add-types-to-methods-defined-with-attr_reader) on it:

It goes something like this:

```rb
# typed: true
class A
  extend T::Sig

  sig {returns(Integer)}
  attr_reader :reader

  sig {params(writer: Integer).returns(Integer)}
  attr_writer :writer

  # For attr_accessor, write the sig for the reader portion.
  # (Sorbet will use that to write the sig for the writer portion.)
  sig {returns(Integer)}
  attr_accessor :accessor

  sig {void}
  def initialize
    @reader = T.let(0, Integer)
    @writer = T.let(0, Integer)
    @accessor = T.let(0, Integer)
  end
end
```